# How to update RDS instance type defined in CDK / Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I have an RDS DatabaseCluster set up using CDK that's deployed and running with the default instance type. I want to upgrade the instance type to something larger and deploy it with (hopefully) no downtime. The RDS docs has a [Scaling Your Amazon RDS Instance Vertically and Horizontally blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/) but it only specifies steps to modify it using the console and not Cloudformation/CDK.

I tried modifying the instance type in the console and then made the changes in CDK and deployed but still got the following error:

> The specified DB Instance is a member of a cluster. Modify the DB engine version for the DB Cluster using the ModifyDbCluster API (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: [RequestID]; Proxy: null)

How do I update the instance types for an RDS cluster defined using Cloudformation/CDK?

Comment: Can you add the code to your question. It's unclear what you have currently. That error is related to modification of the DB engine version and seems unrelated to instance type.

Comment: @BrandonMiller You're right, the issue had to do with the database version. I guess the DB was initially deployed with an older version of postgres and then was upgraded in the console and not the CDK which led to the mismatch and the error while I was trying to solve something else.